# make a glossary with ConTeXt

Tags: context, glossaries

is there a simple way to make a glossary in ConTeXt?
just like with the glossaries package in latex

example : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary

Comment: I found no information about this neither in the context wiki nor in "an excursion"

Comment: Search for abbreviations in te manuals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use the synonym system to make a glossary.

Define:

```
\definesynonyms[definition][definitions][\deffull]
```

Create a new definition :

```
\definition[CONTEXT]{ConTeXt}{The best way to write texts}
```

Use :

```
\CONTEXT
\deffull{CONTEXT}
```

List all definitions:

```
\completelistofdefinitions[criterium=all]
```

More information in : http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definesynonyms
and in the ConTeXt manual

Thank you for your help @Aditya

Comment: I added a [short note](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Latex_Packages#glossaries) about this on the ConTeXt wiki as well.

Comment: Is there a way that Con\TeX t will tell us where a synonym was mentioned as \LaTeX s `glossaries` does it?

Comment: What does the `\deffull{CONTEXT}` achieve? Also would you please answer @NobbZ question?